# Canvas elements changing colors when not supposed to?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make an HTML5 canvas checkers game.

I made a JSFiddle of my project: https://jsfiddle.net/0q6thfq8/

Here is the function that I think might be causing the issue: (line 77)

```
this.drawCheckers = function() {
    this.drawSquares();
    for(var checker of this.checkers) {
        checker.draw();         
    }
    if(this.selection != null) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        ctx.lineWidth = "5";
        ctx.rect(this.selection.x,this.selection.y,64,64);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

For some reason, when selecting a checker, the last black checker gets a green outline.

Due to the uniqueness of the problem I am having, I am having a hard time finding other forum posts and websites that talk about this problem.

Could someone shed some light on this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a `beginPath()`:

```
if(this.selection != null) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.lineWidth = "5";
    ctx.rect(this.selection.x,this.selection.y,64,64);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0q6thfq8/1/)**

This will clear the path before drawing a new selection. Otherwise the old path content would be included.

Also remember that `ellipse()` needs a [polyfill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) in some browsers.